# Paste buffer/clipboard into brand new file?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

I am breaking apart some files, and I'd like to paste what I cut into a brand new file, which I specify the name of. Something like:

```
:c file-that-doesnt-exist.txt
```

Where `c` is a key command.

**Edit** I've found `:e`, but that just takes me to a new buffer with the same clipboard. I would just like to magically dump the clipboard into a new file and continue editing the original file, without seeing a new buffer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A fast way, working on entire lines, is to visually select the lines to move (`V` ...), then:

```
:'<,'>write! >> the_other_file.txt
```

... where `'<,'>` is automatically appended by Vim after you press `:`. This will append the range to that file, creating it if it doesn't exist. Then, a `gv` in normal mode will reselect the range, so you can easily delete it (`d`).

Then, it's even easier - select another range (`V` ...), hit `:` to open command-line, `Ctrl-P` to bring back the last command, `Enter` to copy the lines <sup>1</sup>. Then `gvd` to delete them locally; rinse and repeat.

**Alternatively**, you could "cut" to a named register by *appending* to it (using the capital letter), e.g. on first text selection to cut: `"ad`, then (repeatedly): `"Ad` (on other selected text). At the end, edit the new file and paste from that register (`"ap`).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>Even better, use `@:` to repeat the last command (as [Karl Yngve Lervåg](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/21/karl-yngve-lerv%c3%a5g) suggests in the 1st comment below).</sup>

Comment: Even easier: Use `@:` to repeat last ex command.

Comment: Nice! I modified the post accordingly, even if its position is quite close to your comment :)

Comment: @KarlYngveLervåg what is an 'ex' command?

Comment: @user151841 Ex commands are commands you enter in command-line mode with `:`. See `:help cmdline.txt`.

Comment: @VanLaser I suppose `>>` is the normal command line concatenate? Then I could use `>` to overwrite an existing file?

Comment: @user151841 `>>` is used to *append* lines (concatenate, yes), and `!` to create the file if it doesn't exist. To overwrite a file instead, use `'<,'>write! the_other_file.txt` (without `>>`, and no, without a `>` - it's not shell scripting). See `:h :w!` and `:h :write_a`.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative is, assuming you want to store register a:

```
sp +0put\ a c:\temp\split.txt
```

Alternatively, you can use `:e` or `:tabedit` or even `:new` if you want a new unnamed buffer.

See the help

```
:h :put
:h +cmd
:h :new
:h :split_f
```